# Can I treat a specific warning as an error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, function, warnings, return-value

The following is a simplified version of a pattern I sometimes see in my students' code:

```
bool foobar(int a, int b)
{
    if (a < b) return true;
}
```

The real code is more complicated, of course. Visual Studio reports a warning C4715 (*not all control paths return a value*), and I would like to treat all warnings C4715 as errors. Is that possible?

Comment: Surely you should just treat all warnings as errors. :)

Comment: @GMan: Though in the general case I agree. It is sometimes necessary to be able to specific things.

Comment: @GManNickG - i recently turned on `-Werror` for a project of mine and realized it has a down-side, which is that when i'm developing the code it's helpful to have mistakes categorized as errors or warnings.  I can see "aha, 2 warnings and 1 error" and start anticipating what i probably did wrong better than if i just see "3 errors".   Really `-Werror` seems only necessary if that's the only way to get people to eliminate warnings in the code.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This should do the trick: `#pragma warning (error: 4715)`.
Or the `/we4715` command line option (see [/w, /W0, /W1, /W2, /W3, /W4, /w1, /w2, /w3, /w4, /Wall, /wd, /we, /wo, /Wv, /WX (Warning Level)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx) (courtesy of Tom Sigerdas)).

Comment: Does the `pragma` need to be in all files for it to count or any in the project?

Comment: documentation: [/w, /Wn, /WX, /Wall, /wln, /wdn, /wen, /won (Warning Level)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx)

Comment: @TomSirgedas Thank you for the documentation link.

Answer (score 6):

`/we4715` works for me.

In Visual Studio 2013 anyway, it is in the UI under *Project Settings* -> *Configuration Properties* -> *C/C++* -> *Advanced *-> *Treat Specific Warnings as Errors*. Add "4715".

Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx

(Please note that this page lists the wrong UI property for VS2013.)

Answer (score 2):

I added the following to the (VB)project file and it worked:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">  
<WarningsAsErrors>41999,42016,42017,42018,42019,42020,42021,42022,42032,42036,41997</WarningsAsErrors>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the compiler warning level to level 4 (in Visual Studio) and it will treat all warnings as errors.  It is good practice to have your students compile their code with no warnings and no errors anyway :)

Also, turn on the /WX compiler option.

Comment: No it won't.  Not unless you tell it to.  It's a good practice to set both, but setting to level 4 is not sufficient to make it error out on a warning.

Comment: I forgot to mention the /WX option.  Edited to fix.

Comment: @Zac: on the other hand, at level 4, VS really screams for a whole lot of things that are **not** errors. I much prefer level 3 and `/WX` together.

Comment: @Matthieu: /W4 is fine, but /Wall is the annoying one, giving warnings for stuff in system headers.

Comment: @Matthieu:  It will only scream at you for warnings you create at level 4.  I avoid /Wall as there is nothing I can do to fix Microsoft's implementation of the standard library, yet it will scream at you for it.

Comment: @Zac: I thought it signalled issues in the STL headers too.. may have mistaken it for /Wall :)