# How to treat selected warnings as errors in MS Visual Studio C++ 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I treat a specific warning as an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750880/can-i-treat-a-specific-warning-as-an-error)

I'd like to treat selected warnings as errors in my MS Visual Studio C++ 2008 project. Is that possible?

Answer (score -1):

Go to your project-> properties->C/C++ 
There is an option Treat warnings as errors. you can mark it as yes

Comment: Won't it raise ALL warnings to errors?

Comment: You can modify the compiler warning level - Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750880/can-i-treat-a-specific-warning-as-an-error It gives more options