# How to convert warning C4715 to error

Tags: c++, msys

I am building cpp files using msys Make.exe , and getting the below 
warning c:\ankit_cc\wm2015git\wm-cpp\base\wmautomator\base\wmautomator.cpp(1047) : warning C4715: 'WMAutomator::fetchSerialNumbersBasedOnLpn' : not all control paths return a value ;

I want to make this above warning to error . Please suggest .

Comment: Look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520853/warning-as-error-how-to-rid-these

Comment: But, I have lot of C++ files , so in each file i have to add ,I want to add thia at compiler level , I mean somewhere in msys or generic makefile like Makefile.nt5

Comment: Find out which compiler switch that option in Visual Studio enables and use that in your makefile for all compiler invocations....

Comment: @RedX I am using Make utility of msys , so we can't change it from VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways of doing this

- `#pragma warning (error : 4715)`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e.aspx

- Compiling with `/we4715` option passed to `cl.exe`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx

Comment: This I got earlier from  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750880/can-i-treat-a-specific-warning-as-an-error

But My question is to how to do the same in Makefile , because we can't add pragma in Makefile

Comment: @AnkitDixit - see the 2nd way I added to the answer /we4715 passed to cl.exe

Answer (score 0):

Pass

```
/we4715
```

to the compiler in your makefile.