# How to convert warning C4715 to error ... just for a particuar type

Tags: c++, c++17

Follow up question to
[How to convert warning C4715 to error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25206180/how-to-convert-warning-c4715-to-error)

How do you turn the compiler warning C4715 to an error, just for a particular type?

```
struct lax 
{
    int i;
    lax() : i(0) {}
};
struct fastidious 
{
    int i;
    fastidious() : i(0) {}
};

lax getLax() 
{
    if (false) return lax();
} 
fastidious getFastidious()
{ 
    if (false) return getFastidious();
} 

int main() 
{
    lax myLax = getLax(); // I am fine with this being a warning.
    fastidious myFastidious = getFastidious(); // I want a compiler error here.

    return 0;
}
```

Ideally there is an specifier I can apply to the type `fastidious` that would do the job.

In this particular example, I could use the `#pragma warning (default: 4715)` after the definition of `getFastidious()`.

```
#pragma warning (error : 4715)
fastidious getFastidious()
{ 
    if (false) return getFastidious();
}
#pragma warning (default : 4715)
```

However, I would like something that I can define on `struct fastidious`, that would apply to all functions that return the type.

Comment: a question is..why? both versions are undefined.and in release version both are catastrophic

Comment: And both classes are in the same translation unit? Use `std::optional`

Comment: Good question. Maybe that was not the best example as it begs your very valid point. I tried to find the minimum-simplest example for my question. The answer to your question is that I have some legacy code of the form
lax getLax(bool b) {if (b){return lax(1);}else{return lax(2);}}
 where that is not my immediate worry to fix now. That triggers the c4715 warning, and I dont want these to turn into errors...now.

Comment: With the code in your comment I do not get the c4715 warning. I do with the code in the question