# Treat specific warning as error for C++ project in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, compiler-warnings

I want to treat a specific warning as an error, and I want to configure that in Visual Studio (2019 in particular). From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750880/can-i-treat-a-specific-warning-as-an-error) or [this MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=msvc-170) I know it must be possible. I just con't figure out how to do it in Visual Studio.

My project is a C++ project and I'm in the project settings under C++ / Advanced. There is a field called "Treat Specific Warnings As Error", which has an "Edit" functionality. But what do I enter there?

- The compiler warning as I get it from the build output: `C4390`.
- The compiler switch: `/We4390`

[image: Treat Specific Warnings As Errors dialog]

No matter what I do, when I have a look at the complete command line, there is no compiler switch for that warning.

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the numbers only, i.e. `4390`. For multiple warnings, enter them semicolon separated: `4390;4391`.

If you don't see it in the command line, click the "Apply" button.

In the command line, they will appear as `/We"..."`.